# "Master page" administration in Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple website with Django, where I'm using template inheritance. The "master page" model contains information that is shown on all pages, like a header or footer. I can't hardcode it, since I need it to be editable from the admin pages.

At the moment (some of) my models look somewhat like this:

```
class MasterContent(models.Model):
    title_header = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_header = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProfileContent(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile')
```

Then I render to a view like so:

```
def profile(request):
    return content_shortcut(ProfileContent, 'pages/profile.html')

def content_shortcut(content_class, template):
    return render_to_response(template, {'master_content':MasterContent.objects.get(id=1), 'content':content_class.objects.get(id=1)})
```

Now, I need to render a view from a different app, but I still want the master page content to be passed along. It will become way too messy for my liking if I have to manually include the `master_page` content every time I render a view (even with the shortcut it seems wrong). I tried making MasterContent abstract, but this forces me to re-enter the data in every other model that inherits from it, which is a much worse scenario.

**In short: how can I easily have data available in *all* the views, across apps, which can be edited from a single place in the admin pages, while keeping things DRY!**

*Note*: I also think there must be a more smooth way (something like flatpages) to administrate the content of the profile page than having a model of which I will only ever use one instance/row, but I chose to ignore this for now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like an [`inclusion tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) or even a [`simple tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) should do the job just fine.
You could query the content in the tag and embed the tag in your base template.

And if you need this information on every page [`context processors`](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) might be another option, though template tags are probably preferable for your use case.

Comment: ahh! this is beautiful, now everything is decoupled and dry. awesomeness

Comment: You might find django-snippets useful in your case - chunks of html, editable in the admin (or possibly the front end) - and placed with template tags: https://github.com/rickhurst/django-snippets

Comment: if you need it available on all views then a context processor is the best choice -- be careful too many processors become resource hungry. template tags are an excellent choice for most uses.

Comment: Though almost antique in web terms this is still a good read: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/:  
_For situations where you want to get content out of your database, a template tag is typically the best way to go, but consider a related situation: what happens when you want a particular variable — not a content object — to be available in the context of every template?_

Comment: Custom tags (inclusion/simple/filters) seem to only be available to single apps, according to the Django documentation; is there a way to make them available site-wide?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't understand your question completely, but couldn't you just import the master content?

e.g.

```
from mainapp.models import MasterContent
from mainapp.views import content_shortcut
```

then go about your new view

```
def differentprofile(request):
    return content_shortcut(DifferentProfileContent, 'pages/differentprofile.html')
```

Comment: Yes I could, but I find it wrong (and not DRY!) if I have to do this in every view method.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose, I guess that's sort of the ideology of python though, the pluggable modules. In this way you can write any infinite number of apps, and simply add 'from someapp import SomeClass' to access features of another app/module. Apologies if I misunderstood the way you were trying to do it.

Comment: Well, I feel almost certain that Django must have a way to accomplish this, it's not that rare of a scenario I suppose. Could be that I'm simply looking at it the wrong way :-)

Comment: Also, i think in my example you wouldn't need to import MasterContent, just the content_shortcut, since content_shortcut would handle the import of MasterContext. That's only one import per each views.py -- essentially the content_shortcut is your own custom render method you defined, and now you call that render method, just like you would otherwise have to import render or render_to_response, etc. from the django libraries anyway

Comment: While you are right that this could be done without too much hassle, it would still be wrong by design, since all views would have to know that there even exists master content, and I dont want them to. Your help was much appreciated though!